# Setting the default front page setting to be translatable

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I've enabled the following multilingual modules:

- Configuration Translation
- Content Translation
- Interface Translation
- Language

Configuration translation enables me to translate the site title and slogan, but how can I translate the default front page setting to have a different front page per language?

I can see the setting in `system.site.yml`:

```
page:
  403: ''
  404: ''
  front: /node
```

but overriding it in `language/de/system.site.yml` doesn't seem to help.

Is there anyway I can activate the setting for translation?

Answer (score 1):

I created a proof of concept Drupal (latest - 8.3.5) instance on simplytest.me earlier today to check if this is actually something you cannot override in language//system.site.yml. I had **no problem** to differentiate frontpage for default (english) language and additional language.

Just remember that `front` property is nested under `page` key.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same situation and like described by @zaporylie, the workaround to set the value directly in the translated configuration works perfectly. Did the author perhaps forget to import the changed configuration?

I now opened an issue to expose these values in UI. Please help to contribute: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3097497

Comment: "forget to import the changed configuration?" Not sure. It was four years ago.